# Django JSignature Templated Docs

Tags: django, jsignature

I am utilizing Django 4.1.3, templated_docs, and Jsignature.   I am hoping to be able to place the signature image generated by jsignature directly to the document.

I have attempted almost every combination of utilizing Draw_signature, templated_docs {% image %}, and even {{form.media}} {{form.field}} noted in Jsignature.

any insight here is helpful.

```
from templated_docs import fill_template
from templated_docs.http import FileResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from invoiceManager.models import Invoice
from jsignature.utils import draw_signature
def invoice_view(request, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.get('pk', None)
    if pk:
        # try:
        invoice = Invoice.objects.get(pk=pk)
        information = {
            'repairDate': invoice.repair_date,
            'claim': invoice.claim_authorization_number,
            'customerName': invoice.customer.name,
            'customerAddress': invoice.customer.address,
            'customerCityStateZip': f'{invoice.customer.city} {invoice.customer.state.abbreviation}, {invoice.customer.zip_code}',
            'customerPhone': invoice.customer.phone_number,
            'insuranceName': invoice.insurance.name,
            'policyNumber': f'policy Number: {invoice.policy_number}',
            'VIN': f'VIN: {invoice.vehicle_information.vin}',
            'YMM': f'{invoice.vehicle_information.year} {invoice.vehicle_information.make} {invoice.vehicle_information.model}',
            'customerSignature': draw_signature(invoice.signature),
            'technician': invoice.technician.name,
            'location': invoice.business_location.name,
            'submissionDate': invoice.invoice_submission_date,
            'amount':invoice.invoice_amount, 
            }
        repairLocations = {f'RL{x}':"Repair Made" for x in invoice.location_of_repairs.all().values_list('id', flat=True).order_by().distinct()}
        information.update(repairLocations)
        filename = fill_template(
            'docs/base_invoice.odt', information,
            output_format=".pdf")
        visible_filename = 'invoice{}'.format(".pdf")

        return FileResponse(filename, visible_filename)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the image tag to accept a path allowing the use of jsignature.draw_siganture(, as_file=True).  Creating a temp file that can be referenced by PIL and then redrawn -- less than ideal, but allowed to maintain aspect ratio/size of the jsignature field.

```
from PIL import Image
from django.utils.html import escape
from django import template
register = template.Library()

PIXEL_TO_CM = 0.00846666


class ImageNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = template.Variable(value)

    def render(self, context):
        self.value = self.value.resolve(context)
        images = context.dicts[0].setdefault('ootemplate_imgs', {})
        id = len(images)
        z_index = id + 3  # Magic
        photo = Image.open(self.value)
        width = photo.size[0] * PIXEL_TO_CM
        height = photo.size[0] * PIXEL_TO_CM

        return ('<draw:frame draw:style-name="gr%(z_index)s" '
                'draw:name="Signature" '
                'text:anchor-type="char" svg:width="%(width)fcm" '
                'svg:height="%(height)fcm" draw:z-index="%(z_index)s">'
                f'<draw:image xlink:href="{self.value}" '
                'xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" '
                'xlink:actuate="onLoad"/></draw:frame>') % locals()


@register.tag
def template_image(parser, token):
    _, path = token.split_contents()
    return ImageNode(path)
```